# Convert time data '2019-06-19' to format '%d-%m-%Y'

Tags: python, datetime

Trying to convert %Y-%m-%d" to "%d-%m-%Y". The object im converting is "unicode" from a date input in a form. I need to send this start date to my SQL query to get data from the table for that time.

I've done this previously but it doesn't work anymore as the start_date to be converted is in the format "%Y-%m-%d". It must end up in %d-%m-%Y in my sql query!

```py
   start= datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
   end= datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

  start_time=start.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
  end_time=end.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

I want to convert the received input form form 2019-06-19 to 19-06-2019. Thank you so much. I don't know why i'm finding it so hard.

Comment: when you run this code, you should get a pretty descriptive error. can you paste it?

Comment: Your edit turns your question in a completely different one, where the issue is now caused by a typo. Moreover, none of the answers posted in response to the original question appear to make much sense anymore

Comment: You have the %m and %d in the wrong place in your first example.

Answer (score 5):

You can parse the time string to a `datetime.datetime` using its current format and then format the resulting object with the new format:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(thing, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

For example:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-05-18', "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
'18-05-2019'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is in the right format now - 19-06-2019.  However getting this error so I think i have to convert it back to datetime object? 

'StartTime': start_time.isoformat(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isoformat'


Should I go 
 ```python start= datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime(“%d-%m-%Y”)
 start_time= datetime.datetime.strptime(start, “%d-%m-%Y”) ```

Comment: @MangoKitty, probably? This depends on what your database engine expects. If it expects a `datetime.datatime` object, you shouldn't need to convert it to a string in the first place and use simply `datetime.datetime.strptime(thing, "%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it does and I'm only saying that as in its current state it doesnt have the '.isoformat' attribute with error str' object has no attribute 'isoformat'. I'll let you know how I get on :)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
year, month, date = "%Y-%m-%d".split('-')
"{}-{}-{}".format(date,month,year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

````
import datetime

start = '2019-06-19'

start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')```
````